# Google People API; google token response object null for second time login; ListConnectionsResponse object null always

Tags: java, android, api, google-contacts-api, google-signin

```
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = null;
    try {
        tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, params[0], redirectUrl).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when i log in with google in my app, first time i got token response json, in that i got 4 field values, 
access_token

expires_in

id_token

token_type

then

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
            .build()
            .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);

    People peopleService = new People.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Talent Hive")
            .build();

    ListConnectionsResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = peopleService.people().connections()
                .list("people/me")
                .setPageSize(50)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ListConnectionsResponse object coming null.

but second time the GoogleTokenResponse object itself coming null.

so, i am unable to retrieve list of contacts using GOOGLE PEOPLE API. please anyone help. i am searching for answer very long time.

Comment: Could it be that your access token has expired?

Comment: Possibly does your account have no contacts that are in groups? The list connections call only returns people who are in contact groups.